# Position an element between rows of floating LIs

Tags: css

Using CSS, is there any way that I can specify that an element is positioned in between rows of floating list items in a list.

HTML:

```
<ul>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
</ul>

<div class="in-between">  I want this between the second and third row, even if the window is resized. </div>
```

CSS:

```
*, *:before, *:after {  -moz-box-sizing: border-box; -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; box-sizing: border-box;}
ul{margin:0px;padding:0px;}
li{width:100px;height:100px;float:left;margin:10px;background:green;list-style-type:none;}
.in-between{background:red;height:100px;clear:both;}
```

You can see an example in this fiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/rqCHk/3/

I would like the red box at the bottom to be positioned between the first and second rows, regardless of the width of the browser.

If this isn't possible using CSS, the next best thing would be to do this without worrying about the width change. If there's a way to specify that it's below the first row w/o using JavaScript, that would be great.

Thanks!

Comment: that's not something css is designed for. you can position items relatively, but there's no practical way to tell css "find elements X and Y on this page, then move element Z in between them". That's something you'd need javascript for.

Comment: While Flexbox *can* reorder elements, all of the elements that need to be reordered must be siblings (ie. your div must be a sibling of the li elements, not the ul -- but that would be invalid HTML).

Comment: Thanks @cimmanon. I thought there was a way to reorder elements that weren't siblings, but this makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I worked this up as just a little thought exercise for me. As others have said, this is not a job for pure CSS, but with a little jQuery hackery, it's possible. I worked up a jQuery function to bring this to life, so you can see it here:

http://jsfiddle.net/rqCHk/7/

Here's the jQuery :

```
//Put all the original LIs in an array. 
var oldlis = [];
$("ul.old li").each(function() { oldlis.push($(this)) });

function insertRow() {
    // Count the number of LIs per row
    wsize = $(window).width();
    lisize = $("ul.old li").outerWidth(true);

    liperrow = Math.floor(wsize/lisize);
    rownum = liperrow * 2;

    $.each(oldlis, function(k,v) {
        if( k< rownum) {
            $("ul.new").append(v);
        } else {
            $("ul.old").append(v);
        }
    });
}




$(window).resize(function() { 
    insertRow();
});
insertRow();
```

And your new HTML:

```
<ul class="new">
</ul>

<div class="in-between">  I want this between the second and third row, even if the window is resized. </div>

<ul class="old">
    <li>1</li>
    <li>2</li>
    <li>3</li>
    <li>4</li>
    <li>5</li>
    <li>6</li>
    <li>7</li>
    <li>8</li>
    <li>9</li>
    <li>10</li>
    <li>11</li>
    <li>12</li>
    <li>13</li>
    <li>14</li>
    <li>15</li>
    <li>16</li>
    <li>17</li>
    <li>18</li>
    <li>19</li>
    <li>20</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: This is inside of a sortable, so I don't want to split up the elements into two different ul's. I will definitely do this with JavaScript though. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that it's possible with floats. The only solution I can imagine, assuming the height of `.in-between` is fixed, is using inline-blocks with increased height of the 1st line and absolute positioning ([see fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rqCHk/4/)):

```
li{ /* other styles... */ display:inline-block; vertical-align:top; }
ul:first-line { line-height:220px; }
.in-between{ /* other styles... */ position:absolute; top:120px;}
```